# DOM PDF is displaying an error message if " <thread> </thread>" is used in HTML

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to create PDF using DOMPDF. When I use the following in my HTML it shows an error message and doesn't create any pdf.

```
    <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Website</th>
 </thead>
```

The Error Message

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: include/style.cls.php

Line Number: 948

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute() in C:...

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

It's the `thead` tag, not `thread`.

Edit: and there should be a `tr` around the `th`s.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I mistyped the spelling.. it would be THEAD. but still it is not working.   Getting this message.. Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: include/style.cls.php